# Ensure that users can only access their data in a REST API request

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, oauth-2.0

I'm working REST API right now with Jersey, Spring. Which shall be accessed with an Android/iOS later.
If I have for example user settings like this `@Path("/user/{userID}/settings"`) in a Jersey Resource. How can i ensure that every user can access his/her settings only? I have read a lot about spring-security-oauth2. But as far as i understand you can only verify that the user is really the user but not make a difference if he/she can access other users settings?!

Comment: Just verify the user is authenticated before each request for private data.

Comment: You will probably need an additional layer of security to do what you need. OAuth allows you to authenticate a user, and even assign roles, but you will need to secure each URL path eg. `/user/ABC/settings` and `/user/DEF/settings` separately for the role / permission. The security can either be provided in a layer above the Jersey framework (your load balancer for instance), or inside of it, as per J-Alex's answer below. The second option is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is called authorization.

Authorization can distingush level of accesses of each users. 
It's major topic actually. You can use roles, permissions, ACL for securing the service.

The simplest way for solving your task is to use path `/user/settings` and find the authentication yourseft, like:

```
public Settings find() {
    UserDetails customUserDetails = (CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    return setingsService.findByUser(customUserDetails.getUsername());
}
```

Create your CustomUserDetails:

```
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Authority authority : user.getAuthorities()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName()));
        }

        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    // implement other methods  

}
```

And CustomUserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
            // check if exist
        }

        return new CustomUserDetails(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason why the path has to change, and the call to `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` seems to break the REST principle somewhat... the server side should not need to hold context. The same principle could apply without the security context having been set, by looking at the request only.